# Vertical centering thead in tabularx break when newline text in any column in row

Tags: tables, line-breaking, tabularx

I have the following long table with tabularx.

```
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=.25\hsize\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}X|
    >{\hsize=.5\hsize\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}X|
    >{\hsize=.25\hsize\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}X|}
    \hline
    \thead{Thời gian}
    & \thead{Công việc}
    & \thead{Người thực hiện}
    \\
    \hline
    x/x/xx
    \newline
    -
    \newline
    x/x/xx
    &
    - Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
    \newline
    - Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    &
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
    \\
    \hline
```

[image]

`\thead` worked pretty well. I used `\thead` because I want texts in the header row centered and the content of the middle column to float *left* or `\raggedright`.

The problem comes here when I breaking line `\\` to a random `\thead` like this:

```
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=.25\hsize\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}X|
    >{\hsize=.5\hsize\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}X|
    >{\hsize=.25\hsize\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}X|}
    \hline
    \thead{Thời gian}
    & \thead{Công việc}
    & \thead{Người \\ thực hiện}
    \\
    \hline
    x/x/xx
    \newline
    -
    \newline
    x/x/xx
    &
    - Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
    \newline
    - Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    &
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
    \\
    \hline
```

[image]

The **FIRST** and **SECOND** `\thead` column have changed their anchor and do not center veticaly anymore.

Can you show me how to fix this?

Comment: X uses p columns so aligns on the first line you can define it to use `m` columns using `\tabularxcolumn` you have not shown how you have defined `\thead` nor provided a test document

Comment: Thank you, I'm being new to Latex. Can you show me the code of define `m` columns using `\tabularxcolumn` ?
And I have used the usual `\thead`, so I do not define any on it yet.

Comment: there is no "usual" `\thead` tabularx defines no command of that name.  `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}` would make tabularx use m columns

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I forgot that I had defined the command. There is my command `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}`

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need to use the `\thead` command (from `makecell`). Here  is a simplified version, and some improvements as to vertical spacing in cells, with the help of the `cellspace` package:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{cellspace}
    \setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
    \setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{4pt}
    \addparagraphcolumntypes{X}
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

    \begin{document}

        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=.25\hsize\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}X|
            >{\hsize=.5\hsize\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}X|
            >{\hsize=.25\hsize\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}S{X}|}
            \hline
            Thời gian
            & Công việc
            & Người \newline thực hiện
            \\
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried this before, but it's not for my case. The problem is I want the text in the header row centered and the content of _middle_ column to float left or `\raggedright`. I used `\thead` because it has `\textbf` and _center_ the text.

Comment: @HuyPham: but you have `>{\raggedright}` for the second column. If you also want the second column head centred, replace \raggedright} with `>{\centering}`.

Answer (score 0):

With `tabularray` package the code for your table is simple and short:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\noindent%2,
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {X[1, c,m] X[2,r,m] X[1,c,m]},
             rowsep  = 4pt,
             row{1}  = {font=\bfseries}
             }
Thời gian   & Công việc & {Người\\ thực hiện}   \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Contents in cells you can simply split in two (or more) lines with `{text \\ text}`, for vertical center of them, you only needs to add option `m` to column specification.  For more details of `tabularray` syntax see package documentation.